# How to set value of NMBCLUSTERS in mac os?

Tags: macos, kernel

I am developing a server application for MAC OS which should be capable of handling several thousands requests simultaneously.

I saw that initially only about 2.3 MB of space is allocated to network and as more requests are received by server, allocated memory keeps on increasing until it reaches about 65 MB.

At 65 MB, it shows 100% usage.
Several thousands requests for 'memory delayed'
and also, client connections start to fail.

I checked the value of **kern.ipc.NMBCLUSTERS=32768** which roughly comes to about 72 MB of memory.
So, I want to set new value for this using sysctl command but it says *"sysctl: oid 'kern.ipc.nmbclusters' is read only"*

Google recommends adding kern.ipc.NMBCLUSTERS=65536 in /boot/loader.conf for freebsd system but there's no such directory on mac os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at http://osdir.com/ml/general/2012-04/msg52432.html
Solution is to run command

```
sudo nvram boot-args="ncl=131072"
```

and restart the machine.
After restart, sysctl kern.ipc.nmbclusters will be set to new value of 131072.

Back to testing my app performance now :-)

(Not sure how I can clear this boot-args to reset value)